# Is there an unfolding-folding operation, that will perform a matrix repetition in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, fold, unfold

I have the following tensor in pytorch:

`i1 = torch.randn(1, 32, 320, 640)`

I would like to extract the following sliding blocks

`[:,:,i,0:15], [:,:,i+80,0:15], [:,:,i+160,0:15], [:,:,i+240,0:15]`

`[:,:,i,1:16], [:,:,i+80,1:16], [:,:,i+160,1:16], [:,:,i+240,1:16]`

`[:,:,i,2:17], [:,:,i+80,2:17], [:,:,i+160,2:17], [:,:,i+240,2:17]`

...

`[:,:,i,624:639], [:,:,i+80,624:639], [:,:,i+160,624:639], [:,:,i+240,624:639]`

and repeat for all i, where i = 0,1,2,3,...,79. Ideally, I would like to collect all these blocks back together to a tensor with a size of something like this: `[1,:,32,4,16]`.

I tried using the [unfold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html) and [fold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Fold.html) operations, but without any luck. Any suggestions will be very helpful!

Update with code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as f

i1 = torch.randn(1, 32, 320, 640)

in_chans = i1.shape[1] 
nf       = i1.shape[2]
np       = i1.shape[3]
accel    = 4
step     = np//accel
kernel   = 16

i3       = f.unfold(i1,kernel_size=(1,kernel))
```

`i3` will extract all the sliding [1,16] blocks, but it won't take care of the unfolding for the second dimension. If I use instead `i3 = f.unfold(i1,kernel_size=(accel,kernel))`, I will get all possible continuous [4,16] blocks, which is not the exact dimensionality I need. I need to introduce somehow a dilation over the first dimension of the kernel size.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you meant is that

- the slices are of length 16 each like `0:16`, `1:17`, etc. rather than 15 which doesn't evenly divide 640; and
- if `out` is the ideal result, `out.shape == (1,32,80,4,624,16)` such that `out[k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6] == i1[k1,k2,k3+80*k4,k5+k6]`.

If my understanding is right, you can use [`Tensor.as_strided`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.as_strided.html#torch.Tensor.as_strided) to compute `out` like

```py
out = i1.as_strided((1,32,80,4,624,16), (32*320*640, 320*640, 640, 80*640, 1, 1))
```